# Why I can't display the stacked widgets in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

So, I'm a newbie in Qt. My code below is based from what i understand about QStackedWidgets. My problem is that I can't display the widget in index 0, which is the loginPage. when I run the code, the window that display is the mainwindow.ui window.

```
centralWidget = new QWidget();

loginPage =     new Login;
registerPage =  new Register;
userPage =      new UserAccount;


stackWidget =   new QStackedWidget;

stackWidget->addWidget(loginPage);
stackWidget->addWidget(registerPage);
stackWidget->addWidget(userPage);

stackWidget->setFixedSize(500,340);


layout = new QVBoxLayout;

layout->addWidget(stackWidget);

setCurrentIndex(0);

setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
stackWidget->move(0,0);
centralWidget->move(0,0);

setFixedSize(500,340);

centralWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

connect(loginPage,SIGNAL(changeCurrentIndex(int)),this,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
connect(registerPage,SIGNAL(changeCurrentIndex(int)),this,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
connect(userPage,SIGNAL(changeCurrentIndex(int)),this,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
ui->setupUi(this);
```

Comment: `ui->setupUi(this);` is probably changing your central widget.

Comment: thank you thuga!. its now working.